# Extract items from SQl database and assign to variable

Tags: python, database, qt, sqlite

I have created a small database from which I would like to extract each item from every field!
Simply put, I want to be able to display the items within the UI (Ot.Gui) and the only way I can think about doing is is assigning the items to variables 1 by 1.
1st row, 1st value to last row last value.

At the moment, I am using

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect('Bestellung.db')    
with con:
    con.row_factory = lite.Row
    cur = con.cursor() 
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Bestellung")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print "%s %s %s" % (row["Id"], row["ArtikelNr"], row["Beschreibung"])
```

which extracts and prints all the information from the database: (only 6 values atm)

```
1 a1 b1
2 a2 b2
```

but now I want to create a function or module which automatically creates a variable for each of the items. Such that:

```
Row 1, Value 1 = Row1Val1
Row 1, Value 2 - Row1Val1
...
```

Which I can then use to set the TextLabels.

Unless you have a simpler way to solve my problem.

Thank in advance

Comment: Just wondering, have you seen the QSqlTableModel? It solves this problem completely :) http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtsql/qsqltablemodel.html

Comment: Two usual ways are define a class and a collection of it. Or simply use a collection of hash. List and Dict in python terms. Which strangely enough form the basis of that rows object you are using already

Comment: WoLpH, I have not. This also looks promising but I think I will have to have a detailed look cuz right now its confusing me more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), they're great for that kind of task.

Comment: hey Dugres, this looks interesting. But I still have the problem that I can't assign the values to variables. I can use for emp in map(EmployeeRecord._make, cur.fetchall()):
    print emp.Id, emp.ArtikelNr, emp.Beschreibung which also prints 1 a1 b1
2 a2 b2 but I can't reuse the items emp.Id. Unless I'm being silly. I'm a new user so don't be surprised. Thanks

Comment: @T1M : What do you mean "I can't reuse the items" ? why not ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question well. Do you want to iterate through the columns dynamically without specifying the column names explicitly (that's what I understood). If yes, then this should help you:

```
with lite.connect('bestellung.db') as con:
    con.row_factory = lite.Row
    cur = con.cursor() 
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Bestellung")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    rowcount = 1
    for row in rows:
        colcount = 1
        for key in row.keys():
            value = row[key]
            print "Row %d, Value %d = %s" % (rowcount, colcount, value)
            colcount += 1
        rowcount += 1
```

If not then never mind, I will delete this answer.